# Navigate to url after confirmation

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, sweetalert

Working on MVC 5 app.

I have a button defined as....

```
  @Html.ActionLink("Delete Chart " + Model[0].CurrentChartNumber,                                               
          "DeleteChartData",
          new { eventId = Model[0].EventId, 
                chartNumber = Model[0].CurrentChartNumber },
          new { @class = "btn btn-danger btnDelete" })
```

It's rendered as...

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btnDelete" 
   href="/AuditResults/DeleteChartData?eventId=50&amp;chartNumber=1">
   Delete Chart 1
</a>
```

I am using [sweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) for the delete confirmation. Everything works fine, BUT, I cant get it to navigate to the defined href after the user clicks Yes. Here's the javascript code...

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".btnDelete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to DELETE this chart?',
            text: "You won't be able to undo this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
        }).then(function() {
            //user selected "Yes"
            return true;
        });

    });

})
</script>
```

So, if the user clicks Yes, it should navigate to....

```
/AuditResults/DeleteChartData?eventId=50&amp;chartNumber=1
```

... but it doesn't navigate anywhere. (I even removed e.preventDefault() and tried it.) Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Does it work with a standard `confirm()`?

Comment: A delete action is changing data. It should be a POST not a GET.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the user selected yes, you are not doing anything but returning true from the promise. So try adding redirect to the page you want inside the code block.

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $(".btnDelete").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        swal({
            title: 'Are you sure you want to DELETE this chart?',
            text: "You won't be able to undo this!",
            type: 'warning',
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
            confirmButtonText: 'Yes!'
        }).then(function() {
            //user selected "Yes"
            window.location.replace("AuditResults/DeleteChartData?eventId=50&amp;chartNumber=1");
            return true;
        });

    });

})
</script>
```